# Javascript is not treating my counter variable as a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, integer

I'm trying to generate form elements with jQuery to send to a Paypal form, I'm having issues looping through an array.

The list of items in a shopping cart is held in an array, the Javascript loops through the array adding the form fields and values as follows

```
for (j=0;j<(itemArray.length);j++)
$('#createFields').append("<input type='hidden' name='item_name_"+ j +"' value='"+itemArray[j]+"'/>");
```

This works perfectly, except, I need item_name_ to begin with a 1, not a 0.

"easy" I thought

```
for (j=0;j<(itemArray.length);j++)
$('#createFields').append("<input type='hidden' name='item_name_"+ j+1 +"' value='"+itemArray[j]+"'/>");
```

Should work, but no, that gives 01.

So I figured it wasn't treating "j" as integer

So I tried

```
(j*1)+1
```

That still gave me 01

```
parseInt(j)+1
```

Also gives me 01!

How can I get "0+1 = 1" from this counter variable?!

I can't understand why this issue is happening, I've got over the same problem with the methods above many times before!

I've also tried

```
for (j=1;j<( (itemArray.length+1) );j++)
```

but that just screws up the looping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just group the expression:

```
"..." + (j+1) + "..."
```

this will give `j + 1` a higher precedence so that it is evaluated first and then concatenated.

Otherwise, concatenation with the string will take place first, that is, first `j` is concatenated with the preceding string and then the resulting string is concatenated with `1` (left to right evaluation). Without grouping, the expression is implicitly evaluated as:

```
((("..." + j) + 1) + "...")
```

Comment: Arghhhh... so simple! I thought I'd tried just about every variation! Was starting to go slightly mad!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
for (j=0;j<itemArray.length;j++)
{
 $('#createFields').append("<input type='hidden' name='item_name_"+ (j+1) 
  +"' value='value='"+itemArray[j]+"'/>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
for (j=1;j<=itemArray.length;j++)
{
  $('#createFields').append("<input type='hidden' name='item_name_"+ j +"'value='value='"+itemArray[j-1]+"'/>");
}
```